# php code to remove similar elements in an array element

Tags: php

```
 Array
 (

    [0] => 16WW07,CSE,Hanumanth,100,8,1,7,0,0

    [1] => 16WW07,LPIO

    [2] => 16WW07,LPIO,Deepika,100,65,63,2,0,0

    [3] => 16WW07,USD

    [4] => 16WW07,USD,Mantej,100,5,4,1,0,0

  )
```

i want to remove similar elements like [1] and [3]. I have used `array_unique($arr)` but it is not working. 
I need output as
for above array i need array as:

```
array([0]=>16WW07,CSE,Hanumanth,100,8,1,7,0,0                                                

[1]=> 16WW07,LPIO,Deepika,100,65,63,2,0,0                                            

[2] =>  16WW07,USD,Mantej,100,5,4,1,0,0  )
```

Comment: You have not told us your desired results.

Comment: if `16WW07` is a similarity factor - they are all similar. Elaborate your question

Comment: I m getting the same array no changes

Comment: you need to specify your expected output here

Comment: for above array i need array as [0]=>16WW07,CSE,Hanumanth,100,8,1,7,0,0                                                [1]=> 16WW07,LPIO,Deepika,100,65,63,2,0,0                                            [2] =>  16WW07,USD,Mantej,100,5,4,1,0,0

Comment: ok....................

Comment: @sudarshannayak, you still didn't specify the similarity criteria

Comment: i think 16WW07,LPIO is similar between array elements [1] and [2] right?

Comment: @sudarshannayak, but you said *similar elements like [1] and [3]* earlier, now you're saying *array elements [1] and [2]*

Comment: array element [1] has similarity with [2] and [3] has similarity with [4] this is what i wanted to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to filter the array by the number of occurrences of commas:

```
$myArray = array_filter($initialArray, function($item) {
    return substr_count($item, ',') > 1;
});
```

Or you can simply loop the array and unset the key where a single comma is found:

```
foreach ($initialArray as $key => $value) {
   if (substr_count($value, ',') === 1) {
       unset($initialArray[$key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but array_filter is not working in my php version its 5.0.5

Comment: Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_FUNCTION at line array_filter(..)

Comment: I just edited my answer.. you can simply use a foreach loop to do the same thing without using array_filter

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can't see the missing `)` where is it?